# What mechanical Keyboard for taking programming heavy CS courses?

Tags: keyboard

I am looking for a mechanical keyboard to use in the 4 or more CS courses I'll most likely be taking next semester. I don't care about programmable buttons for WoW. (no offense to gamers, I'm trying to get efficient with my school work). I am looking for typing speed. I am trying to decide which color switch I should get. I've looked at these articles and this is the extent of my education on mechanical keyboards. A sturdy keyboard I could take with me and pull in and out a backpack would be a plus. From my understanding, I want to avoid Cherry MX Red & black and should consider Cherry MX Brown and Blue. I'll have a roommate and will be in public spaces so if a quiet model of a mechanical keyboard exists, that'd be helpful, although I don't think mechanical's have a rep for quietness. Being quite is a secondary priority as I'll move to a lobby if someone is trying to sleep. It seems like brown is quieter but is that at the expense of typing efficiency? Care more about efficiency and will find a place where I'm not disturbing people if needed. I haven't tried out either, and if people have opinions based on product experience, that would be awesome!

Any other features to look for besides switch color would be appreciated. Also, I want my buttons to have symbols and am not ready for something like Das Ultimate Keyboard. I am leaning to the [Das Keyboard 4C Professional Compact Mechanical Keyboard.](http://shop.daskeyboard.com/products/das-keyboard-4c-professional-compact-mechanical-keyboard/) I dont care as much about number pad and am open to 60% keyboards also.

I am looking for model suggestions on top of specs and switch colors. Once I decide a switch color, there are still so many brands to sift through. What would be the best keyboard for me programming in my all classes?

Budget isn't the biggest concern as long I can get the keyboard most suited for my needs on my first purchase. I know first purchases never work like that, but trying to get as close as possible. If I do well in my classes, I will be able to get better internships and work on side projects, so a good keyboard is a worthy investment.

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-choose-the-best-mechanical-keyboard-and-why-you-511140347

I tried searching stackexchange but couldn't find an answer. Sorry if you think this is a repost but there aren't specific up to date answers I could find addressing everything including switch colors. I'm not asking y'all to do my homework. Just guidance from fellow CS majors.

Comment: Sorry but this really has NULL to do with programming and SO is only for programming. Superuser or similar stackexchange sites are a much better place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think this is what Stack Overflow is for.  That being said:

You seem to have misconceptions about keys switches; I don't know who told you not to try Cherry MX Blacks or Reds, but they were wrong.  You should try some keyboards in store or buy a switch tester to see what switches work the best for you, because they are all good, so it comes down to personal preference. Blacks and Reds are linear switches, so personally I went with MX Blacks for school, because unless you are bottoming out on every press linear switches should be quieter (no click or bump of tactile switches).  Cherry MX switches seem to fall into three categories: linear (no bump or click), tactile (has a bump as you reach activation point), and clicky (audible click and tactile bump as you reach activation point).  Browns are tactile, while Blues are clicky, so for your roomates sake I would get Browns if those are the only two you are looking at.

If you can find a board with MX Clears, those may also be to your liking, as they are basically stiffer browns (like how Blacks are stiffer Reds, and Greens are stiffer Blues).  Some people prefer stiffer switches because they are heavy finger typers and bottom out too much otherwise (which can put some strain on your fingers after a while), while some people find the stiffer switches too tiring if typing a lot.  You really need to test a few kinds first.

I use a Poker II keyboard.  It is 60%, so it is easy to take to school, and is almost the exact width of my Surface Pro 3 tablet, so they go well together.  It is a very popular board for a few reasons: sturdy and well built, programmable keys, my version came with thick PBT keycaps (which are a little more textured than your standard ABS keycaps, and don't shine as fast), and it has standard sized spacebar and other keys, so you can easily buy a new set of keycaps that will fit.

I suggest reading more on the mechanical keyboards subreddit if you still need more info or have other keyboard questions.